# Swift SKPhysicsBody Collision Issues

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, operator-overloading

So I'm trying to work with two `SKPhysicsBody` objects. I was looking at some tutorials to help work with the collision mechanics and dealing with that.

I pulled this code out of one of the tutorials:

```
    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
        var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody
        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
            firstBody = contact.bodyA
            secondBody = contact.bodyB
        } else {
            firstBody = contact.bodyB
            secondBody = contact.bodyA
        }


        if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & ColliderType.Bird != 0) &&
            (secondBody.categoryBitMask & ColliderType.Edge != 0)) {
                birdCollideWithEdge(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode)
        }

    }
```

My `ColliderType` is set up like this:

```
enum ColliderType:UInt32 {
    case Bird = 1
    case Edge = 3
}
```

The error I'm getting comes from this line:

```
 if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & ColliderType.Bird != 0) &&
            (secondBody.categoryBitMask & ColliderType.Edge != 0))
```

The error is

> Could not find an overload for '&&' that accepts the supplied
>   arguments

I've tried casting the `0` as `UInt32` and also casting the `firstBody.categoryBitMask & ColliderType.Bird` as `Int` but that didn't help.

I also tried bringing the `firstBody.categoryBitMask & ColliderType.Bird` out of that and setting it as it's own variable thinking that maybe there was just too much going on in that if statement but that didn't fix anything either.

Can anyone help push me toward the right documentation that might help or let me know if this won't work under its current setup.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**: Adding `rawValue` to the end of `ColliderType.Bird` fixed my errors.

Comment: Are you sure `firstBody.categoryBitMask & ColliderType.Bird != 0` returns a boolean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rawValue` of your `enum` this way:

```
if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & ColliderType.Bird.rawValue != 0) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & ColliderType.Edge.rawValue != 0)) {

}
```